# Javascript - Search for string with optional hashtag

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having some difficulties converting my python regex to javascript. If my needle was 'apple' or '#apple', both case insensitive, I'd want to match any of the following from a haystack:

```
'apple', '#apple', ' apple', ' apple ', '#orange#apple'
```

Here is my python regex:

```
r"\b#?apple\b"
```

My feeble attempt at converting this to javascript was :

```
/\b#?apple\b/i
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the word boundary `\b` after the `#` char:

```
/#?\bapple\b/
```

Comment: Just remove the first boundary, between `#` and `a`, `\b` will always match.

Comment: @kassens: no, because `#` is optional, without `\b` the regex can match `Mapple` that is not wanted.